# How to generate the Zip using powershell with in same folder

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

Step1 : need to zip below three files in same location with holds.zip
Path: D:\Project\extensions\files inside this path having 
households filefolder
xmldocument
dll need to zip the file with these three files
Step2:once zipped(holds.zip) delete the zip file and copy in  D:\Project\extensions

using this command but not getting the required output
Compress-Archive -Path D:\Project\extensions\files -DestinationPath D:\Project\extensions\files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried re-creating the scenario you mentioned as follows:

Created a directory "D:\Project\extensions\files" that contains the following items:

1. A File Folder named "datadocs"
2. An XML file named "script.xml"
3. A DLL file named "config.dll"

[image]

I executed the below PS script and it archived the folder contents in same location:

```
$compress = @{
  Path = "D:\Project\extensions\files"
  CompressionLevel = "Fastest"
  DestinationPath = "D:\Project\extensions\files\holds.zip"
}
Compress-Archive @compress
```

[image]

Once the zip file was generated, I used the below cmdlet to delete it & move to "D:\Project\extensions" path:

```
Move-Item "D:\Project\extensions\files\holds.zip" "D:\Project\extensions\holds.zip"
```

[image]

Hope this solution meets your requirements!